# A question on battery life calculation

Tags: batteries

There is a 24V 50Ahr battery unit.

An smps voltage regulator converts it to 5V and couples to a device. This 5V drives 100mA constant current.

So to calculate battery life roughly, should I use currents or powers delivered?

Is the answer: using current transfer 50A/100mA or using power transfer (24V*50A)/(5V*100mA)?

Comment: it is an smps actually

Comment: @PeterJ ok so you mean since smps is not linear we cant employ the currents right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amp hour rating means the battery can supposedly deliver 50 amps for one hour.  Note that this could be 25 A for 2 hours, 5 amps for 10 hours, etc.  In other words, it is in units of charge.

The voltage rating says it can do this at 24 V.  Charge times voltage is energy, which is the energy the battery can supposedly deliver before being depleted.  This energy is (50 A)(3600 s)(24 V) = 4.32 MJ.

Now look at what rate you are draining energy, which is (5 V)(100 mA) = 500 mW = 500 mJ/s.  To drain the whole battery energy therefore would take (4.32 MJ)/(500 mW) = 8.64 Ms = 2.4 kHours = 100 days.

**However**, that doesn't take real world battery issues into account, and ignores inefficiencies in converting from the battery voltage to 5 V.  Let's say the conversion is 80% efficient.  Guessing what the battery can really do is more tricky.  You have to look at the battery datasheet carefully to decide what its capacity really is under your conditions of discharge rate, temperature, age, number of cycles, etc.  For a single use battery, you can be more aggressive.  For a rechargeable, you need to derate more since the capacity goes down over time, with the number of cycles, how deeply it was discharged, how long it was held in various states.

Let's say that you've decided that due to the very low discharge rate for this battery, the temperature, etc, you will only get 30 Ah capacity at the end of its service life.  That's 60% of the theoretical.

So in this example we get 80% due to power conversion and 60% due to battery usage, for a total of 48% overall.  Therefore the estimate would 48% of the theoretical 100 days, so 48 days or "one and a half months".

Answer (score 2):

With a switching mode converter you would use a power conversion formula. You do need to consider that some of the electrical energy will be used up in the converter and converted to heat. So the formula becomes:

Time = (Input Capacity * Converter Efficiency) / (Output Power)

If for sake of simplicity you could consider that battery voltage stays constant during the time the battery capacity is consumed that becomes:

Time = (24V * 50AH) * (0.78) / (5V * 0.1A)

Of course your efficiency may be different than 78% and the 24V is likely to decrease as the battery becomes depleted.

Comment: Its not 50A (current), its 50Ahr (capacity).  Output power * time) = input voltage * capacity * efficiency.    -    Time = (input voltage * capacity * efficiency) / (output power)

Comment: @JImDearden - I know. The formula is meant to result in a time estimate. I edited to make that more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The ampere hour rating of a battery will naturally assume that the battery terminal voltage has dropped significantly below the nominal fully charged value and it's probably safe to assume (worst case etc.) that to fully extract the full 50 Ah, the battery terminal voltage may be as low as 12V. You will need to read the data sheet of the battery to get this information of course.

Because you are using a switching converter (possibly 90% efficient) you can assume the power into the load plus 10% will be extracted from the battery but, given that the battery voltage will droop possibly down to the 50% level, the current taken from the battery to service the load power will ramp up to 200% as the battery discharges.

This complicates the analysis but a simple spreadsheet calculation with several points should give a reasonable result. Temperature is also a factor.

Read the data sheet for the battery is my advice first to establish the lowest operating point of terminal voltage.

Comment: How bout Time = (12V * 50AH) * (0.78) / (5V * 0.1A) as wrost case? I just changed 24V to 12V. Could it be worse(shorter time) than this? There is no details on battery